# How to clone a repository from GitHub in windows 10?

Tags: github

I have git in my windows 10,
and trying to clone a repo from github.

but get stack:
that the command-

**git clone git@github.com:dockersamples/node-bulletin-board.git**

but the results-

**Cloning into 'node-bulletin-board'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

if I try this command-
**git clone https://github.com/dockersamples/node-bulletin-board.git**

I get-

**Cloning into 'node-bulletin-board'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dockersamples/node-bulletin-board/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

I wonder what's the diffrent between:
HTTPS, SSH, GitHub CLI.

If any one of you can help me I would be so happy :)

Answer (score 1):

You must add .git at the last while cloning.
Try

```
git clone https://github.com/dockersamples/node-bulletin-board.git
```

HTTPS is nothing but this top https.git,
github cli is command line interface which also the same thing